# Memory Leak Springboot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an application that seems to be using too much memory. I have been trying to find the source for a while. But still no luck.

I have read several articles pointing at JPA as the culprit for some of the memory issues with Spring Boot. I only have a single repository so I cannot imagine it be the issue.

```
@Repository
public interface  WordRepository extends JpaRepository<Word, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT w FROM Word w WHERE w.value IN (:words)")
    List<Word> findAllIn(@Param("words") List<String> words);

    Word findFirstByValue(String value);

    @Transactional
    Long removeByValue(String value);

    Page<Word> findAllByCategory(Pageable pageable, String category);
}
```

I have another class which is a helper for dropping the table. I cannot do that with JPA (that I know of) so I am getting a hold of the persistance object and using it to truncate the table.

```
@Service
public class WordRepositoryHelper {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "default")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public int truncateWordTable() {
        final String sql = "truncate table word";
        entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql).executeUpdate();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I am using them as in here.

```
@Service
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class CSVResourceService implements ResourceService {

    @Autowired
    private WordRepository wordRepository;

    @Autowired
    private WordRepositoryHelper wordRepositoryHelper;

    private static final String HEADER_ID = "id";
    private static final String HEADER_VALUE = "value";
    private static final String HEADER_CATEGORY = "category";

    @Override
    public Boolean save(MultipartFile file, Boolean replace) throws Exception {

        // some other code

        if (replace) {
            wordRepositoryHelper.truncateWordTable();
        }

        //some other code
    }
}
```

Any guidance on the issue or suggestion.

Comment: So what's your question? Is your code going to use a lot of memory?  Why don't use some profiling tool before blind guessing?

Comment: I assume your project has lot more other functionality other than jpa . For memory issue may be your guess is right , but Use a profiling tool to find exact objects responsible . U ll save time guessing n invalid assumptions. Is it loading a lot of data from database

Comment: How can "JPA" be a culprit of memory leaking? It is a series of INTERFACES! Do please at least provide memory dumps if you are going to claim something about memory leaks

Comment: Keep in mind: lots of memory usage is NOT necessarily a memory leak! In order to track down any of them, you absolutely must use a memory profiler, [MAT](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/) is great and will probably do for 99% of the times. Having some kind of automation to "exercise" your application (e.g. JMeter for web apps) is also invaluable. It helps to reveal leaks and other memory problems AND prove that you corrected them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks a lot for all the suggestions in the comments. As you might have guessed this is the first time I am dealing with memory issues and since it was happening in production I panicked a bit.

So the real problem was not really JPA. It was more like a combination of problems and issues. And like some of the comments suggested I had quite a few candidates to blame for my memory problems:

- JPA
- Tika
- Opencv
- Tesseract

This is how I solved my issue:

1. Educate. Go out there and learn a bit about the problem and how it could be solved. Here are a few links I used:
   https://www.toptal.com/java/hunting-memory-leaks-in-java 
    https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/08/14/find-fix-memory-leaks-java-application/ 
   https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=java-understanding-solving-memory-problems
2. Use the new knowledge and pull some graphs and understand your memory situation. Trust me this exploration revealed a whole bunch of stuff that I did not know was happening. (like some Chinese characters array, my guess Tesseract needs it for OCR)
   [image]
   [image]
3. Then use `-Xms256m -Xmx512m` when executing your jar so you can narrow and see who to blame. Also it will limit the resources in the server.
4. All this lead me to two possible causes of leak and trouble in general.
   1) [Using POI or Tika to extract text, stream-to-stream without loading the entire file in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043720/using-poi-or-tika-to-extract-text-stream-to-stream-without-loading-the-entire-f) 
   2) [Memory Leak from iterating Opencv frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050499/memory-leak-from-iterating-opencv-frames)

And that's it I think I am ok now.

Thanks to all for the help.